# ZFS on Linux for RHEL/OEL Installation

Tags: installation, zfs, rhel6

I'm trying Oracle Linux (OLE) 6.1 (Red Hat RHEL 6.1 compatible clone).
Actually I'm not familiar neither with RHEL nor with OLE.
I want to try ZFS on linux for RHEL as provided in [this guide](http://zfsonlinux.org/spl-building-rpm.html) .

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

I added OL repositories and successfully installed "Development Tools".

Next in guide is

```
./configure
make rpm
```

But I do not know where should I run it.

So questions are:

**Where should I run *./configure* ?**

**Where should I run *make rpm* ?**

By [ZFS on linux guide](http://zfsonlinux.org/spl-building-rpm.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you attempt the regression test suite included in those instructions? I agree that their instruction list is confusing, but if you have successfully executed the yum command then, based on these instructions, you should have the necessary software installed.

Comment: After ./configure I have to make rpm and install spl, spl-modules-devel, spl-modules-devel RPMs. For now they are not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to download the release from the ZFS on Linux website and uncompress the tar.gz file (`tar -zxvf filename.tgz`) in a directory. Changing into the directory, you should then be able to run the rest of the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for very immediately answer. It was very silly of me. You are right. I have to download and unpak spl and zfs tarballs first.

Answer (score 1):

[Go Here](http://zfsonlinux.org/) and download the packege you want (probably spl-0.6.0-rc6), then do the `tar -zxvf filename.tgz` where the filename is the file name of the downloaded file, then cd in to the directory that have benn created, then you should run the commands you have mentiond in the same order. 
and it should run flowlessy.

BTW In the link above there is an already rpm or deb packeges so i think it would be more convinieate for you to install them.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried Ubuntu with ZFS on linux. It is pretty well and simple to install. There is unofficial [repo](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable).